# QAction with icon displays checkbox on top

Tags: c++, qt

I have a menu with checkable QActions in it: (ed: these calls are within a QWidget subclass, so 'this' points to the associated widget).

```
QAction* action = new QAction(icon, actionName, this);
action->setCheckable(true);
action->setActionGroup(m_actionGroup);
menu->addAction(action);
```

This menu is attached to a tool button, which is in a QWidget with a few other tool buttons. Previously, it was part of a larger widget, but I've been refactoring to confine some things together.

When it was previously part of the larger widget, these actions and their icons displayed fine. Now, however, the icons are drawn in a dotted pattern and a box for a check box is drawn on top. When I hover over an action, the dotted action goes away entirely, and it's just the check box. When I select an action, the icon appears normally.

I've tried doing the same in a little toy program, and the menu displays correctly then, so I'm having trouble reproducing the issue outside of my rather large program. Has anyone seen behaviour like this before, or know how to fix it?

Qt 5.5 on Ubuntu 16.04 is the platform information.

Edit: It gets even stranger. The original implementation created the QMenus without parents. Which I would have avoided because of memory leak concerns. But if you create the menu with the widget holding the button as a parent, then you get this behaviour. It's something about the QMenu being constructed with a parent that is creating issues, not the QAction.

Comment: Maybe instead of `this` you should use a pointer to your widget?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer above; The function calls were being called within a QWidget, so 'this' is the pointer to the widget it relates to.

Comment: @shavera You could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and show an image of what you get and what you want to get.

Comment: I tried to create a minimal example, but couldn't reproduce the behaviour observed in the larger program, as I note in my original comment. I understand that makes it very difficult for others to possibly answer the question, but I was hoping that other people might have come across this before.